# How to make my navbar fit the max width value while not having enough content?

Tags: css, reactjs, width, styled-components

So I have a navbar that has like 4 links and I need it to be a specific width, and i want it to be responsive so I used `max-width: 65em`, however this results in it not being 65em unless theres alot of content inside which isn't there cuz of the nature of a navbar.

How do I make my nav bar content have a width of 65em while being responsive when i decrease screen size? Do I have to mess with media queries and breakpoints for is there a solution?

Navbar code:

```
const Nav = styled.nav `
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 65em;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`

<Nav>
      <Logo to="/">saif</Logo>
      <NavLinks>
        <StyledNavLink to="about">About</StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink to="projects">Projects</StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink to="coding-challenges">Coding Challenges</StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink to="contact">Get in touch</StyledNavLink>
      </NavLinks>
</Nav>
```

Comment: What "specific width" did you want? `width:100%` combined with `max-width:65em` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Nav = styled.nav `
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 65em;
  width:100% ;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`

<Nav>
      <Logo to="/">saif</Logo>
      <NavLinks>
        <StyledNavLink to="about">About</StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink to="projects">Projects</StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink to="coding-challenges">Coding Challenges</StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink to="contact">Get in touch</StyledNavLink>
      </NavLinks>
</Nav>
```

Try giving width to nav in percentage .
I have given 100% , you can change it to your convenience.
Try running this code .
I hope this solves your issue .

Comment: thanks yeah width 100% coupled with max-width does the trick. However i added that to the parent element of the nav bar and in the nav bar i now only use width 100%. Cuz turns out my parent element was the one facing the width problem not the nav

Comment: Nice .
Upvote the solution so that it solves doubts of others as well !

Comment: I did, is upvoting different from accepting it as correct?

Comment: Yes, upvoting helps the solution to stay at top !
Accepting it as correct means that you are accepting the fact that my solution is correct !